# I'm trying to find a Harry/Snape fanfiction that had a healer named Kieran who was a friend of Severus

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, severus-snape

It's about Harry Potter working up to the final battle. Its au during 6th or 7th year (no camping trip) before Dumbledore died.

Harry ends up working with and being trained by Severus and they get closer and start a relationship. Severus trains Harry in a barn and has a healer friend Kieran that helps him train sometimes.

At one point in the story Harry and Severus go to a potions convention and Harry (in disguise) is his 'assistant' but it's obvious he's really just his 'boy toy'.

I think I read it in early to mid 2000s and it was definitely completed. It was at least 50,000 words but could have been over 100,000 words.

Comment: https://fanfiction.net/s/11844769/1/

Comment: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/3780602/1/ is a better match on the catamite angle, but no mention of a "Kieran" or "Keiran".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The querent has confirmed that it was "[Death Eater takes a Holiday](https://archiveofourown.org/works/7876387/chapters/17989165)" by Lee Lee Potter.

> Albus spells a few Order members back to their seventh year age, and sends them to spend time at Hogwarts for a holiday. The Headmaster’s intent is for them to learn that Harry is indeed mature for his age, so that he will be accepted as a full member. What will happen when Severus returns from his time as a teen, to find he has spent the better part of the week entwined with a certain Gryffindor? And, how do their lives change afterwards?

Kieran first appears in chapter 33, I believe.

> Severus nodded and stepped into the fire. He had so much to think about he decided not to think at all just yet. He really needed to get out of his bloody robe. As he stepped into his bedroom he immediately felt the cool air. Spelling the room warmer again, Sev remembered Albus' request. He lit a fire and threw in a pinch of powder from a small box on the mantel. "Kieran Donnelly," Sev called into the fire. A moment later the head of a man with wiry brown hair and a three-day-old beard appeared.

It does involve a relationship between Harry and Snape, although the only mention I see of a potions conference or convention is in a story that Snape tells about his father, the Dark Wizard:

> "Good memory," Severus commended him. "He was not a nice wizard, but at some point he became aware that I was to replace him. He had angered the Dark Lord and was going to be killed as soon as my training was complete. Slowing down my training would be obvious, so instead, he taught me everything he knew, every single detail and nuance to potion brewing known only to Masters. Then, to continue my education, he took me to symposiums, conferences, and helped get me connected with ingredient suppliers all over the world. He always had a full agenda to show our Master that he still had things to teach me."

I'm pretty sure I found it with a search for `hpfandom.com snape kieran`. I had discounted it as an answer because I figured the de-aging part would have been pretty memorable, and because I could find no mention of the conference.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by ibid, this may be Amyria's "[The Unwanted One](https://fanfiction.net/s/11844769/1/)"

> Harry has always wished for someone to care, for a family of his own. On his birthday, he finds out that a certain Potions Master is his father, but Severus has just settled into life with his other son. Can Harry finally have the family he has longed for, or will he always be the unwanted one? Severitus. AU 6th year.

Kieran is the other son mentioned. However, doing searches, no mentions of conventions or "boy toys", the latter likely because Harry is Snape's son.

Comment: I found both of these options while searching Google. The story was originally on hpfandom.net which is gone now. Kieran was a grown man who was friends with Severus for years, from somewhere between the age of 17 and 35, but no one else in the story really knew. There was no extra sons or brothers, the story was canon through book 5 at least before diverting slightly.

Comment: Hmm... so probably not Death Eater takes a Holiday (https://archiveofourown.org/works/7876387/chapters/17989165) where Snape is friends with a healer named Kieran, and he and Harry are together, but there's a major plot point of Snape getting de-aged at the beginning as a "vacation" from Albus.

Comment: Side note, https://archiveofourown.org/collections/hpfandom has a collection of some fics saved from there.

Comment: https://archiveofourown.org/collections/hpfandom/works?utf8=%E2%9C%93&work_search%5Bsort_column%5D=revised_at&include_work_search%5Brelationship_ids%5D%5B%5D=1600&work_search%5Bother_tag_names%5D=&work_search%5Bexcluded_tag_names%5D=&work_search%5Bcrossover%5D=&work_search%5Bcomplete%5D=&work_search%5Bwords_from%5D=50000&work_search%5Bwords_to%5D=&work_search%5Bdate_from%5D=&work_search%5Bdate_to%5D=&work_search%5Bquery%5D=&work_search%5Blanguage_id%5D=&commit=Sort+and+Filter&collection_id=58717 are ones that fit your criteria

Comment: OMG @fuzzyboots you're a wonderful researcher! Death eater takes a holiday is it! I've been looking for this for ages. I had forgotten about the opening premise of deaging professors. THANK YOU! <3

Comment: @HSmalls: Ah. I posted that as a separate answer if you want to accept it.